# IntelliJ IDEA can't resolve type conflicts on code it correctly decompiles

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, ide

My code is:

```
if (client == null) {
    // this can happen e.g. during a graceful shutdown
    throw new ImapTaskRunnerRetrievalException("user " + user + " not found (provisioned null)");
}
```

Which gives the error

> Incompatible types.
>   Required: java.lang.Throwable
>   Found: me.unroll. ... ImapTaskRunnerRetrievalException

even though when I command click on this thing I get

```
  // IntelliJ API Decompiler stub source generated from a class file
  // Implementation of methods is not available

package me.unroll.emailfetcher;

public interface ImapTaskRunnerSource {
   // ...
    static class ImapTaskRunnerRetrievalException extends java.lang.Exception {
      // ...
    }
}
```

Not sure why IntelliJ is so confused. The files live in different Maven/Nexus repos but it clearly found the code, so I'm not sure why it's being contradictory.

I have a similar issue on this method:

```
logger.error(CloudwatchMarker.RangeCachePoolRejectedTask.get(), "rejected range search on start", exc);
```

Error:

> Cannot resolve method 'org.slf4j.Marker, java.lang.String, Exception)

Even though command clicking through to `Logger` gives this:

```
public void error(Marker marker, String msg, Throwable t);
```

Answer (score 0):

Configure an SDK, e.g., JDK. Not doing this causes really wonky problems.